# Workflow in SharePoint sending 2 email when the case is resolved

Tags: workflow, email, notifications

I have created 2 case in SharePoint to notify customer when the case is created and resolved.

In the notify customer when the case is created workflow, I have ticked start workflow automatically when the item is created in the start options with workflow

`If Current Item:Contact Email is not empty`

`Email Current Item:Contact Email`

which sends one email to customer when its created and working fine.

In the notify customer when the case is resolved workflow, I have ticked start workflow automatically when the item is created and changed also tried to just tick changed, in the start options with workflow

`If Current Item:Status equals Resolved`

`and  Current Item:Contact Email is not empty`

`Email Current Item:Contact Email`

which sends 2 email to customer when its resolved instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no wonder your workflow is sending 2 emails.

Consider your workflow is executed for the **first time** when Item is created.

1. Workflow execution will reach at first condition
2. It will check if `Contact Email` is not empty, then fire an email if its true
3. Workflow execution reaches second condition, where the status is not yet Resolved so it will skip.

So here only one email is fired which is fine.

Consider your workflow is executed for the **second** time, when item is changed.

1. Workflow execution will reach at first condition
2. It will check if `Contact Email` is not empty. (**Note**: *Here is the catch. even at first condition your email if fired*)
3. Workflow execution reaches second condition, where now status is Resolved and contact email is also not empty. So an email will be fired.

So there is a bug in your first condition. You need to fix that, because in both cases it will fire an email.

**Solution**: Add an extra condition like status is not equals Resolved, or whatever helps you solving a problem.

`If Current Item:Status **Not equals** Resolved`

`and  Current Item:Contact Email is not empty`

`Email Current Item:Contact Email`